# Build dynamic UI in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, user-interface, actionscript

'Hi --

I'm changing the way I build my UI from this:

If ( role == 'Admin' ) myComp.visible = false;

...to a totally dynamic UI based on what is returned from the DB. I'm architecting the best approach to this now.

I've read about role-based access control and understand that it's best that the server generates the UI after a user is authenticated, but apart from re-doing the entire backend to store MXML et al., is there a better approach?

Is it a bad idea to have a Permissions object that has properties like:

showTabOne:Boolean = true;
allUserToEditGrids:Boolean = false;

The components visibility and includeInLayout properties will be bound to these values.

The UI will also allow a user to create new roles and set permissions.

The only drawback I see is that every time a new feature is added, the app will have to be recompiled to update the bindings.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission object is fine, if you have complex enough policy, it is natural to abstract it into its own class. About recompilation - bindings can be set in runtime ([BindingUtils](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html)), maybe you can use it to avoid it. Not sure what is

> re-doing the entire backend to store
>   MXML

Normal way would be MXML controls composed after the authentification, indeed.

Comment: So, you're seeing to use a BindingUtils.bindSetter() method with the creationComplete() handlers in components to determine what is shown or not.

Answer (score 1):

Be advised that someone can spoof a feed or flashvar to create a permission object to get themselves the credentials they require in a client app, allowing them to view/edit supposedly restricted content/areas.

A good approach for this would be, upon server authentication of the user and role, return a manifest xml defining what part of the ui is visible to the user and bind to those properties.

You can take security one step further and put restricted areas in flex modules to be loaded at runtime when the user navigates to that section. Before the module request is returned from the server, validate the user's right to load that module and return an error code if they are not logged in or do not have the role required for that module.

Storing mxml serverside for dynamic view generation is not a tenable approach. Yes you *can*, no you should *not*. Non-trivial use of the site would bring down the server with a quickness unless you implement a good caching mechanism.

See [Web-tier compilation of MXML files](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=apache_1.html) for more info though as it's an interesting concept.

Comment: I'm using Blaze DS to connect to the DB. The data that is returned to me will be typed objects in Java that are mapped to AS objects; there is no need for XML. That should prevent someone spoofing the permissions returned.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Flex Chimp](http://code.google.com/p/flexible-chimp/) and [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_enterprise_security.html) that describes it.

Comment: Flex Chimp is pretty cool, I like it. It seems to be a very similar approach to the BindingUtils.bindSetter() above; where a role is used to set permissions and then components are directly manipulated via 'removeChild', 'enable', etc..

Comment: The only worry I have is that when a user creates a new role, how will I get that role name in order to create a new line of metadata with it.

Comment: You could push that info to the client through BlazeDS/LCDS Messaging.

Comment: I don't think so, but you can have some classes that read the metadata and then are mutable.